# Is it considered rude to draft other random cyclists?

Tags: commuter, etiquette, drafting

On my commute to work, if there a cyclist in front of me, is it rude to catch up and draft?  To effectively draft I would usually need to be within a foot of their back wheel.

There are two situations:

**Trainers**
There is one part of the commute that is often used by individuals and groups of riders who seem to be training rather than commuting. Generally I would draft these guys if I can sprint to catch them.  As they are going quicker than I can sustain, I never take a turn at the front.

**Commuters**
I think any fellow commuter is probably ok to draft and if they slow down enough I'll take a turn at the front.

Comment: I ultimately think it depends on *where* you're drafting. Around here there are established bike paths that are *just* for cyclist. So when I drafting - I tend to only do it there. Safer since there aren't cars to contend with. Safety first.

Comment: Whatever answer, that is one reason why bicycling, even being an individual vehicle, is indeed a collective mode of transportation, since such level of iterpersonal interaction and cooperation is impossible while driving. I think that, when done respecfully, drafting can even be a way to find new friends.

Comment: See Also: [How close do I have to be for effective drafting (while commuting)?](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/1601/how-close-do-i-have-to-be-for-effective-drafting-while-commuting)

Comment: I would find this rude (and it's happened to me), but I think the real question here isn't whether it's rude to draft without permission, but whether it's safe to do so.

Comment: Based on the responses, your question appears to be [chatty and open-ended](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask). What's the real core question you're trying to answer? "Should I draft while commuting", "Can I draft while commuting", "How can I draft while commuting"?

Comment: Currently discussing this question [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/1882066#1882066).

Comment: If you draft behind me, you should do it carefully because I wiggle around a lot.

Comment: Seems although there are different opinions on this one, it's not entirely an open-ended question.  Tough to choose a right answer on this one unless someone wants to try and sum everything up?

Comment: back-link https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/41216/what-does-draft-mean-in-draft-a-cyclist/

Answer (score 40, accepted):

There was a post on this subject on [The Guardian Bike Blog](http://www.guardian.co.uk/environment/bike-blog/2011/aug/25/cycling-commuter-drafting-etiquette).

I think there are a couple of issues with drafting random cyclists:

- it could be unsafe, particularly if they don't realise you're doing it.
- some people will object to being drafted - it can be considered an invasion of your [personal space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_space).

I think your best bet is to ask before drafting, then there's no problem.

Comment: The problem with asking is that there's generally no good way to do this.  You can't generally pull up alongside and carry on a conversation, and something like a simple "On your wheel!" is unlikely to be understood by those most likely to object.

Comment: And a 'discussion' of the Guardian article on [Bike Snob NYC](http://bikesnobnyc.blogspot.com/2011_08_01_archive.html).. conclusion: Don't do it!

Comment: Completely agree with this.  If someone came up behind my wife and started "drafting" her they'd probably get pepper-sprayed.

Comment: You can't pull up alongside and have a conversation with other cyclists? As someone who does this frequently, this is news to me.

Comment: Bear in mind that it also foists on the draftee the responsibility to think for two people rather than just one as they're riding.  This is the reason I don't like having people behind me: it's extra mental work that I'd rather not have to deal with on an already stressful commute.

Comment: I find that I am ok with it if the person actually chats with me, because then it's just two people riding together. If they just sit back there sucking on my wheel without saying a word I feel used. And I'll probably take some evasive maneuver.

Comment: @StephenTouset Once one or two people drafted behind me on a descent with car traffic, maybe they didn't even draft, but were too close anyway. I didn't notice. I saw a fountain and braked hard because I was low on water and didn't want to walk back up too far. They had to swerve into traffic to avoid me (and overtaking traffic had to swerve into the opposing lane to avoid them). Of course sometimes it's possible to talk, but in this case it would have been impossible. In some cases it's impossible that's the point I think. (ever since I pay special attention to possibly drafting people)

Comment: Surely you can see that there's a material difference between drafting someone at 15mph on a flat road—and making yourself known in the process—versus sneaking in behind someone unnoticed at 25mph+ on a descent.

Comment: @kekekela Your wife randomly peppersprays people on bikes? This seems harsh. On busy cycling paths around me it can happen quite often, that I am behind the same rider for a prolonged time. I am not entirely certain how close one has to be to draft effectively but I would assume that even a couple meters behind would give me a bit of an easier time

Comment: @StephenTouset This is forbidden by the traffic laws of many countries.

Answer (score 24):

This is a potential minefield. If someone's on my wheel, to be honest I don't care. I prefer not to draft when commuting - I know the state of most of the roads I regularly use and I want decent visibility of the surface and other road users; it's a commute, not a heads-down speed session, so a few extra seconds at a lower speed is of little consequence.

Taking over at the front needs careful thought to, especially to make sure that it doesn't look like you're cutting in or, in my case, suddenly blocking me from taking the line I want - not everyone wants you to 'take a turn'.

There are enough dangers on the commute in busy traffic that drafting is probably dangerous, if not rude, if they are random others.

There are some further thoughts and interesting comments in [this recent article](http://www.guardian.co.uk/environment/bike-blog/2011/aug/25/cycling-commuter-drafting-etiquette).

Answer (score 15):

Drafting behind a group that's already in a paceline is one thing, but drafting behind some random commuter is a great way to get into a wreck.

A random commuter isn't going to necessarily know to (or want to be compelled to) inform you when he/she is slowing or needing to make a sudden movement. And are you really getting any benefit whatsoever from drafting behind someone going 15mph? What's the point?

Answer (score 10):

Yeah, it's a touchy situation.  Some won't mind it at all, some won't notice (and will therefore make hazardous moves), some will silently seethe, and some will get downright nasty.

When I was a regular commuter I would draft occasionally when the cyclist ahead of me was obviously a skilled one (ie, all the right clothes, fancy bike, etc) -- though, to be honest, in most of those cases I couldn't keep up anyway.  I wouldn't usually draft someone in street clothes on their Huffy (even though I could keep up with those).

On organized rides I'm a little more likely to take advantage of drafting, though one must be careful there since often riders in a group behave dumbly as they chit-chat.

(And I'll admit that I lower my standards a fair amount in a strong headwind.)

[I'll add that I'm talking here about drafting on straight bike trails and lightly-traveled rural roads.  Drafting in heavy traffic or in a "downtown" road layout is ill-advised at best.]

[I'll also add that when you are drafting without permission you should not get right up on the wheel of the guy in front of you, but rather should maintain 2-4 feet of separation between your front tire and his rear one.]

Answer (score 9):

I'd be more concerned about safety that etiquette.

When in a bike group and drafting behind someone who knows you are there, they are much more likely to keep a good lookout for road debris and other obstacles and smoothly adjust their line/path in order to not screw the drafting person over.

If I'm by myself (or am unaware of anyone drafting behind me) a lot of the time I dodge stuff with my tires at the last second. Most of the time I cut it close enough that if someone was behind me they wouldn't have time to react and would end up running over a lot of road debris.

Comment: That plus the fact that a drafter does not have sufficient safety distance to react on an emergency brake. Drafting may be ok in a road race, in normal traffic, it's not.

Answer (score 8):

Drafting/pace-lining is great but you really have to ask FIRST. After that it is a question of trust and knowing your own skill as well as the other rider(s).

I think we can all agree, however, that starting to draft somebody without notifying them is a definite breach of etiquette and safety.

Answer (score 6):

I would call this behavior rude and dangerous outside of an organized ride or a small group that rides together often and expects it.

Cyclists *should* be [taught how to handle drafting](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/5955/is-it-considered-rude-to-draft-other-random-cyclists/5961#5961), similarly to how auto drivers are taught to handle tailgaters. (It'd be nice if cyclists were taught how to ride at all.) However, this is not the case: Cyclists are taught how to stay upright and, if we're lucky, that they should obey traffic laws. The reality of the situation at present is that cyclists don't expect this and don't know how to handle it.

When you draft someone, it's so they can take some of the wind. Would you walk up to a random pedestrian and hand them your shopping bags? Of course not. Drafting someone without their permission is similar behavior. Drafting is normal and expected in, say, a pace line, or when riding with a friend, but not on the roads with a random cyclist. But I think there needs to be at least an expectation that it will happen.

Also: In general, when drafting, it's assumed that you'll take a turn at the front. If you can't sustain somebody's pace for long, don't ask to draft them, and certainly don't do it without asking.

Comment: Does drafting a rider slow that rider down?

Comment: auto drivers are taught how to handle tailgaters? Never seen this.

Comment: Sure, we learned in drivers' ed. We were told to tap the brakes very gently if we feel it's safe, or to wave them around. At the very least, any driving school or program should teach students that tailgating is dangerous and should be avoided.

Comment: Your shopping bag comparison is unfair: drafting someone does not cost that person any energy. Other issues are more relevant, like safety and personal space.

Comment: @Torben - Considering that riders in a group take turns pulling, there's either an energy cost to the person pulling, or people think there is; either way, it's rude. Would be willing to listen to data showing this hit in energy is negligible, however.

Comment: In a group there's an energy cost to being drafted when the alternative is drafting someone else. Being drafted actually uses slightly less energy than riding alone - the air pressure on your back is slightly increased by having another cyclists close behind.

Comment: Oh, yikes, @NeilFein Some driving instructors might have taught people to tap the brakes on tail-gaters but it is not recommended now:    https://www.wikihow.com/Handle-Tailgaters-on-the-Road

Comment: @NeilFein Being at the front of the group is only as hard as riding solo at the same pace. The point of rotating is that you're trying to go faster than a solo rider for a given power (or at the same speed at less power), so you take it in turns to pretend to be solo. Having somebody draft you doesn't slow you down. Drafting works essentially because the air behind a cyclist is, to some extent, being pulled along with them (you can feel this by standing at the side of the road when a truck comes past) so, if a second cyclist is in that space, they're effectively getting a tailwind.

Answer (score 4):

I end up having to evaluate this on a rider-by-rider basis.

Typically if I've caught up to someone, then I'm going faster anyway, so I'll just pass them and keep my own pace. If someone passes me, then I try to keep up...

Sometimes you see a guy on a high-end bike, who is obviously skilled, and is constantly pedaling and varying his effort for slopes (as opposed to pedal, coast, pedal, coast)... These people are usually OK with it.

If they start drafting you after you pass, and they eventually re-pass you, then its game-on.  I don't mind leap-frogging back and forth taking turns drafting, and the person in front basically trying to loose the tail. It makes otherwise boring rides more fun.

Some people really want nothing to do with it, and you can usually tell because they will suddenly increase their pedaling effort to loose you, instead of maintaining pace.

Typically though, I'll come up to someone, or as someone is passing me, say 'hi' and try to make conversation if the speed difference isn't too great, or we get stopped at the same intersection.  If they aren't willing to say 'hi' back or just nod and ride on... they probably don't care for you drafting off them.

The one time I really don't care is when I'm out on my hardtail mtn bike, and a road biker passes me. I'll draft and keep up with them for a couple hundred yards purely to annoy them that a mountain bike is pacing with them ;)

Answer (score 3):

Commuting 35 miles each day from St Albans to Wood Green for 2 years I never had anyone complain about drafting.  It was generally seen as normal.

Near everyone I came across on the commute would want to race and drafting was just part of that, trying to keep up with the guy in front.  I never found it to be dangerous as you can only really do it on the open road.  In heavy traffic you're filtering and just getting through is challenge enough.

Of course, all of these riders are skilled, experienced cyclists.  I've even had a few guys say thanks for the challenge or make "better luck next time" comments.

All in all, it's part of the sport in my opinion.

Comment: That is a good commute - do you go straight down the A5 or something?

Comment: St Albans, Colney Heath, South Mimms, Barnet (through the park), Colney Hatch Lane, Ally Pally, Wood Green.  It's just over 18 miles each way.

Comment: Sounds interesting, just wondered if you were able to take the dead straight Roman road door to door..

Answer (score 3):

It's not only rude, it can be very dangerous if you don't make sure they know you are there.

I remember once hearing quite a loud angry yell and crash behind me when I actually stopped for a stop sign.

I tend to do hard front-wheel braking, and I guess he assumed we were going to blow right through it.
He probably was simply following too closely though, not actually drafting.

If I'd known someone was there, I might have behaved differently.
I now always wear a mirror.

Comment: You were fortunate the follower didn't collide with you.

Comment: Welcome to Bike Exchange. This answer is more of a comment. You could edit it to answer the question and still add in your experience, or just put it as a comment to another answer.

Comment: @TedHohl, thanks. Somehow I managed to explain my first line without actually typing my first line.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add 2 cents.

It's probably not rude. But it is most likely a bit dumb to draft random cyclists in front of you.

When drafting, I want the leader to take charge and be in control of the roadway. So, that means I need to trust the leader. In a random situation, how do I trust the leader?

That's why I don't draft behind random folks in front of me.

Answer (score 1):

i find it very wrong and an invasion of my personal space. please don’t do it someone says i don’t like it!
Fremantle WAust 32 km round commute daily!

Answer (score -2):

**No it is not rude!**

Drafting should be taught at school as part of a Cycling Proficiency Test so that some conventions are established. This would encourage people to cycle together, taking turns up front and doing so more efficiently. Elbow twitches to get the guy behind to take a turn need to be an accepted convention and ladies not wanting a 'crafty drafter' behind them should be able to use this if they are not happy with whomever is following them.

Every time you draft someone that thinks it is rude you are helping to break down their 'hostile' attitude. The truth is that one should be flattered to be drafted, particularly if you are old, with a rubbish bike or carrying loads of stuff. Drafting goes on, whether you like it or not, and the reality has to be lived with. If you really do not want to be drafted you could always put a big sticker on the back of your seat saying 'DO NOT DRAFT!' - 'L' plates for the bike as it were.

Clearly there is the problem of stopping suddenly for some drafter to go into the back of you. However, there are ways to deal with this potential threat. First of all, think of who is the most scared of a crash - you or the guy behind? The guy behind is not going to be right on your wheel if they are not experienced enough to draft close up. If they know what they are doing and know every pothole in the road then they might be up tight.

By convention, in a crash, it is the guy that goes into you that is at fault. You could have a car door or other instant stop requirement, however, if some cyclist goes into the back of you during such an incident, you do have to ask yourself a few questions about your own riding and not just blame the other guy. Even though the roads are full of hazards it is for you to anticipate and ride accordingly.

As for 'providing a wheel' there should also be some convention to signify that this is being offered. Cut too close in front of someone and you can have some wheel entanglement, go past too fast and they ain't going to make it. When riding with a weaker rider and wanting to put in a good collective time successful drafting makes all the difference and it really should be taught at an early age.

Incidentally, my 20" wheel 'shopping bike' is excellent for drafting. It is about a foot shorter at either end and that extra bit of proximity really helps whether up front or behind.

Comment: Actually, a loaded touring bike makes for a great front wheel bike. (I do this all the time on tours - but it's a situation where it's understood by both parties.) A loaded bike up front and a bike with a trailer in the rear works very well. A bike loaded with ill-attached stuff... that'd be another matter.

Comment: I think I'll get a "DRAFTERS WELCOME" sticker for the back of my bike/bum.

Comment: @JamesBradbury Get a "DRAFTERS WELCOME" sign, with attached disclaimer form and pen that cyclists behind can read and sign before latching on! >;-D

Comment: "Drafting should be taught at school as part of a Cycling Proficiency Test so that some conventions are established." But it isn't, so there are no such conventions. The rest of your answer seems to be predicated on being in this alternate universe where drafting is taught and conventions are widely understood.

Comment: *No it is not rude!*  ***WRONG***  Drafting imposes serious safety concerns on the lead rider.  Doing that without asking is somewhere on the continuum of arrogant to ignorant.  Either you arrogantly don't care that you're imposing those conditions on someone else, or your ignorant of the safety considerations you're imposing on the lead rider.  Just because *some* cyclists don't mind being drafted doesn't change that. "Without asking permission or even telling you, I'm going to ride in a way that puts us both in danger if you do things like try to stop."  You *really* think that's not rude?

Answer (score -2):

**It's over politically-correct to say "you cannot do it" or "you have to ask permission".**

When commuting I find that "drafting" sort of happens **naturally** or by accident.

This type of "drafting" is very different from racing drafting. You cannot be safe and draft at speed right on the wheel of someone you don't know! It is more like companionable cycling, there has to be alot of awareness (preferably by both riders) and you have to anticipate and give a lot of space.

**Asking for permission doesn't make sense . . .**

I find that it's not really that possible to chat / ask permission as "drafting" will start by accident when a rider slightly faster than another overtakes and the overtaken person can then keep up and draft. Mostly there is a difference in ability and the overtaken is not able to speed up and take turn in front. You are sort of stuck as due to benefit of draft you can keep up, this is your natural pace and even if you drop your natural pace off you might well be together again at next set of traffic lights.

If I catch up with someone and realise we are going the same speed more or less then that's a tricky one. I can stay behind. Or I could try to overtake but I think this might be a bit rude if the speed difference is not big and you are probably going to not be able to pull away clear of them.

There's a long steady uphill section on my commute home mostly with mixed on-road and shared foot/cycle path. I often find I'm riding at the same pace as other cyclists so drafting happens somewhat naturally. I don't find that taking turns happens at all much. Especially, of late, when the cyclist in front is on an ebike! :-)

I don't think it makes sense to ask for permission in this situation as all that is happening already is you are travelling at the same space. If permission is granted or denied then what are you going to do? You might be accidentally together for a while anyway!

**Is it rude ?**

I don't think it is rude ...

- if done in a careful way
- and as pointed out - it is not rude if you communicate!

**Communication is good . . . leave the other cyclist know you are there.**

Yes, a bit of communication would ensure it is not rude.

I do try communicate alot on the road. (using traffic signals and voice)

I think I'm a bit shy communicating with other cyclists if moving at a good pace. I would be more concentrating on riding.
You might exchange a word if you stop at traffic lights.

In commuting you don't say hello to everyone who passes(maybe that would be nice! :)). Also, by the time someone has overtaken and you realise you are comfortable in draft your moment to say hello is sort of passed.

Hmm. I could try out something like, "oh, I seem to be behind you now, er, hope that's ok. I'll be careful." 
Hmm, well actually, thinking about it, I'm not too bad really, in front or behind I call out hazards, intentions and signals I'm making. Hopefully not too disconcerting for the other cyclists.

**Most cyclists do not mind?**

I said before something like "Depending on relative speed and road situation **common sense** prevails.". However I think I was wrong. As pointed out elsewhere people think differently. My *common sense* might not be the same as yours. **SOLUTION: Communicate!**

Sometimes someone would overtake me or I would catch up behind but think it doesn't make sense to overtake here . . and I end up cycling behind someone. And it is a bit unclear if they are aware of me or not.

A bit awkward but I guess safer and less rude if communication happens.

I like to drive/cycle defensively and find I generally have good awareness of riders or any traffic ahead and behind of me . . so I think that makes me more comfortable with someone tagging along sometimes.

On **SAFETY**:

This "drafting" is not like racing bike drafting.

I find riding as a pair like this is better for safety against car traffic.

If in behind someone assume they are not as aware or might be less experienced. So you have to be vigilant to hazards ahead (and behind) and anticipate for both of you!

If ahead of someone (OR even if you think you are alone!) similar applies. Always communicate and signal to that imaginary rider/car/other behind that may or may not be there.

Defensive riding techniques apply as always.

- you have to be HYPER-aware of what is coming up in front as well as road situation all around/behind
- you cannot draft right on wheel expecting signals as in road racing. It is an informal arrangement! (there is still good drafting benefit and more safety a bit back and off to the side)

When drafting like this I try to be of safety BENEFIT to the cyclist in front.

- You can back off frequently and **give space** as the cyclist in front encounters hazards, make it clear you are not going for overtake and making space for them to do so.
- move to the side to look in front and behind, (be careful to try and not block the view of the front rider if they look behind)
- signal to front and behind and look after both yourself and others.
- voice call out hazards, intentions and signals you are making
- safety check and signal and claim the road lane early if it looks like you have to move out to avoid hazard/overtake/...
- I generally have flashing lights on and I have a bell too :-)

  - "ding" means "I am here"
  - "blink blink blink" means "I am coming/here/going"

Bells . .

I don't know is this just Dublin, Ireland, but many cyclists don't have(illegal here) or use bells. I find the tinkle of a bell + voice from well back mostly gives good enough warning to pedestrians/dog walkers/other hazards(:-)). Warning enough that multiple cyclists can pass in a friendly way as opposed to all coming to a grumpy slow halt or blazing past close by in a dangerous manner.